# Load Assemblies from a folder other than bin

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a mvc 3 project, the namespace is [POC.MVC.PluginHost]. The controller namespace is [POC.MVC.PluginHost.Controllers]. I created a class library project and change the name space of it to [POC.MVC.PluginHost.Controllers].

class library project code :

```
namespace POC.MVC.PluginHost.Controllers
{
    public class BasicExampleController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // Add action logic here
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public ActionResult Display()
        {

            return Content("");

        }
    }
}
```

I compile it and copy to bin directory of mvc project, when I browse `http://localhost:xxxx/BasicExample/display` it works fine, but I want to copy this compiled dll of class library in a other folder like [plugin] but it is not work, it is working only when I copy it to the bin folder of my mvc project. Is there is a way to solve this problem?

edit .....................................

i test   in my web.config like :

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <probing privatePath="Plugin" />
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

but this not work !!!!

and i test this But this still does not work .....

```
    static System.Reflection.Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        string assembliesDir = "Plugin";

        string aa = System.IO.Path.Combine(assembliesDir, args.Name + ".dll");
        aa = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, aa);
        Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(aa);
        return asm;
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += new ResolveEventHandler(CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("SamplePlg");

        System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new AssemblyResourceProvider());

    }
```

Comment: what's the problem with it being in the bin?

Comment: can you be more specific about the error, ie. is there an exception if so what's the message and type of exception

Answer (score 5):

#### See also

> [C#: Custom assembly directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594214/c-custom-assembly-directory)

You can add additional search paths to your app.config that it looks in to load assemblies. For example

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="lib" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```