# Fluent NHibernate can not auto create mappings for a dynamic assembly

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, automapping, dynamic-assemblies

I am working on a legacy code base that builds some of its entities on the fly.I'd like to be able to add these entities to my auto persistent model using `AddEntityAssembly` like this :

```
var model =new AutoPersistenceModel()
                .AddEntityAssembly(Manager.RunTimeEntityType.Assembly)
```

When I try to build a configuration using this model I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException` which confuses me because the assembly is already loaded to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` and I can build a new object of `RunTimeEntityType` using `Activator.CreateInstance`

Do I have to do something extra ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found out what the problem was.Actually NHibernate had to load this assembly from a different folder that was not introduce as part of the references path.So all I had to do was to add this folder to app.config :

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <probing privatePath="my folder name" />
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594214/c-custom-assembly-directory) there's a question about the same issue.