# c# setting copy local to false when referancing another assembly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reference, assemblies

I have been building a c# project.My main project references some other assemblys.What I need to do is place all this assembly in seprate folders.Assume I have 3 referance assembly and their paths are c:\lib1\assembly1.dll , E:\somefolder\assembly2.dll , C:\docs\debug\assembly3.dll. For my case I need to referance all these 3 assembly to my project but I could not copy them to another folder since their paths are constant and they need to remain there.But when I referance them and try to run my code it gives error saying assembly could not load. Is there a solution for this problem.I am using vs2012 64bit windows 8.1. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not have an answer, but ... go to the referenced assembly in your project and look at its properties. Does it say copy? Start with what works.

Comment: Your application needs to find referenced assemblies. Multiple answers to that, so why do you not what them copied?

Comment: Expecting the CLR to herd these cats is going to have a disappointing outcome.  Especially on the user's machine of course, it won't have a e:\somefolder directory.  Copy the DLLs, that's why the option exists.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [<probing>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w(v=vs.110).aspx) section in the configuration file
   to define directories to be searched when loading assemblies
   However, these directories must be sub-directories of the
   application folder. (see also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594214/c-custom-assembly-directory)).
2. You can also place your libraries in GAC.
3. You can subscribe [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=appdomain.assemblyresolve) event which occurs when the resolution of an assembly fails. In the event handler you should look for assemblies in custom directories. If you find one you should return it from the handler and it will be sued by the runtime.

Answer (score -1):

This is caused because may be you are trying to load a assembly that is 32bit and your application is running under 64 bit mode.

Ensure you do not have 32 bit assemblies depending-on/referencing 64 bit assemblies.

Edit 1:

If the assemblies are loading perfectly when copied locally then In this case their must be some problem with the access rights to the specified locations.

Comment: I think this is not problem because if I put all referanced dlls to my exe location they loaded correctly.