# Need dll files (References) in another subfolder after build

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, build, reference

I got a C# project and I use some 3rd libraries as references.

When I build my project, both exe file and dll files are in the same folder (DEBUG FOLDER by default), but
I want those dll files to be in "libs" subfolder (for example).

Is it possible to do it? 
Here is an image, that I do want to do.
http://oi59.tinypic.com/skyknc.jpg

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594214/c-custom-assembly-directory

Comment: I think answer found by @GeorgeVovos cover all request in the question. If something still not clear make sure to update the post with exact details you need clarification on so it can be re-opened (or ask new question).

Comment: Side note: I've removed excessive "new here", "thank you", "searched alot" text from the post - please avoid adding it back as such text does not provide any additional information about your problem. Feel free to discus it on [META](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it) if you believe that adds important details.